# MySQL: Left Join RIGHT JOIN GROUP BY Error

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM dept_managers 
LEFT JOIN departments 
   on departments.dept_no=dept_managers.dept_no
RIGHT JOIN employees 
   on employees.emp_no=dept_managers.emp_no
```

The once I add group to the query it does not work:
***SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column*** <- what does this mean?  How do I formulate the query?

```
SELECT * FROM dept_managers 
LEFT JOIN departments 
   on departments.dept_no=dept_managers.dept_no
RIGHT JOIN employees
  on employees.emp_no=dept_managers.emp_no 
GROUP BY 
  dept_managers.emp_no,
  employees.emp_no
```

[image]

Comment: I think the error is quite clear.  Using `select *` with `group by` just indicates a broken query.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding the "group by"?

Comment: @Kevin I only want to display the most recent position held by employee.  So once the GROUP is working I can sort by date DESC.

Comment: @Nelles Where is the data field for the employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly put the
   dept_managers.emp_no,
   employees.emp_no

in the SELECT clause